# How to use a FOR loop in a 'struct' subindex? - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, struct

I have a struct as shown in picture, and I need to address one of the columns in a FOR loop, as shown. But I keep getting this error:

Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'struct'.

Error in analisa_arx_teste (line 351)

In my case, what i want is :line 1 represents i = 1, line 2 i =2; So, for features, When I ask for pref_estemod(i).features is to get the values from the field features associated to each model.

I am just starting programming with matlab, so all your help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

```
for i=pref_estemod(1:npreferred)

[m,n]=size(Training);

features=(pref_estemod(1,i).features);

end
```

[image]

Comment: Why `eval()` .?

Comment: It was not necessary. I took it off but the error is the same.
Im cmd i can type, for example pref_estemod(1,1) and it works fine, but is not working with the index :/

Comment: Can you show the code including the `for` loop?

Comment: Sure, I am so sorry. It is edited!

Comment: In my case, what i want is :line 1 represents i = 1, line 2 i =2;
So, for features, When I ask for pref_estemod(i).features is to get the values from the field features associated to each model.

Comment: What exactly do you intend `i=pref_estemod(1:npreferred)` to mean? Integer sequence up to `n` (in which case you need i=1:n) or something else? (If it's something else, please edit in the question.)

Comment: Yes, this is it!

Comment: Please Argyll can you set your answer as an answer so I can check it as correct?

It worked just fine!
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies in `i=pref_estemod(1:npreferred)`.

If you intend to use `i` for indexing, the syntax is `for i=1:npreferred`.

`1:npreferred` itself expands to the horizontal array `[1,2,...,npreferred]`. `=` with a leading `for` is a special syntax combination. It means do the following code with `i=1`, `i=2`, ..., `i=npreferred`. Now I am sure you already know the idea behind `for` loop. The reason I write all this is to give you the following warning/advise. Do NOT expect the same syntax to work with non-numeric arrays. Because it works in some cases and not others.

Comment: What is “it works in some cases and not others“ supposed to mean? `for a=A` always works in the same way: each iteration of the loop uses a different column of `A`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I have seem cases where `a` takes on the value of the whole array `A`. So it means exactly that. If I recall correctly, it was a string array. And version is 2019a. I don't have the example anymore. (In hindsight, I should've asked a SO question with the example back then.)

Comment: @Agryll: If the array is a column vector, then there's just one column to iterate over. I bet that is what you saw.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: As long as memory serves, I never use column vector to iterate over. I might've made that strange decision in order to mimic the output of `x:y:z` syntax way back in the days. But I'll keep in mind the possibility you mentioned for the future.